# How to add text to a WPF Label in code?

Tags: c#, wpf

I feel stupid but cannot find out how to add a text to a WPF Label control in code. Like following for a TextBlock:

```
DesrTextBlock.Text = "some text";
```

What is equivalent property in Label for doing it?

```
DesrLabel.??? = "some text"; //something like this
```

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Try `DesrLabel.Content`. Its the WPF way.

Comment: its just the ContentControl way actually.

Comment: That seems a bit inconsistent, given that the property is called `Text` for a `TextBox` but not for a `TextBlock`...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft there is no obligation for the content of a Label to be text. It is of type `object`, so you can make it any WPF or .NET type you like - a button, an image, a green rectangle, even a `SqlDataReader` if you really want! (though quite what that would represent in a label, I'm not too sure...)

Comment: when update .Content for a WPF label, it does not always refresh the label. How do we force refresh when control yields to the UI?

Comment: @DavidJeske are you in another thread? Dispatching might be the trick

Comment: @DavidJeske imho the best way is to bind the `.Content` to a property in code behind and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for that property (I know late answer, but others might stumble over this question - as I did :-))

Answer (score 34):

In normal winForms, value of Label object is changed by,

```
myLabel.Text= "Your desired string";
```

But in WPF Label control, you have to use .content property of Label control
for example,

```
myLabel.Content= "Your desired string";
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe you want to set the `Content` property. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx) has more information on what is available to a label.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Content property on pretty much all visual WPF controls to access the stuff inside them. There's a heirarchy of classes that the controls belong to, and any descendants of ContentControl will work in this way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use TextBlock control and assign the text property.

Answer (score 0):

do not forgat to add x:name to your MainWindow.xaml

Answer (score -2):

`Label myLabel = new Label ();`
`myLabel.Content = "Hello World!";`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.