# Setting the value of a Label?

Tags: c#, wpf, label

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add text to a WPF Label in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902464/how-to-add-text-to-a-wpf-label-in-code)

I need set the value of a Label like this:

```
messagelb = "Generating file..."
```

I try with `messagelb.Text` and `messagelb.TextIput`

but not work.

how can I do this?

Comment: **Please provide more detail**

Comment: WinForms? ASP.Net? Silverlight? MonoTouch? WPF?

Comment: Is in WPF, how can set the content property?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

in wpf

```
messagelb.Content = "Generating file...";
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using WPF you need to set the Content property.

Edit:

```
messagelb.Content = "your text...";
```

Comment: Yes is in WPF, how can set the content property?