# How do I SUM a query result from SQL database table column and display result in a label?

Tags: c#, sql, label

I want to total the values of 2 columns (`MilesLadenToll`, `MilesLadenNonToll`) from a table (`FuelTaxTripSummary`) based on my query (see select statement below).

I am new to C# and have only been able to display query results in DataGridView and get a total for some columns and then display the total in a text box. I would like to simply display the totals without having to list all the query results in a DataGrid View. What is the best way of doing this?
I would really appreciate examples of working code, since I new to C# and SQL.

My connection string is stored in a global variable:

```
dbSettings.dbConnString
```

Example of my select statement is:

```
select MilesLadenToll, MilesLadenNonToll 
from FuelTaxTripSummary 
where WorkMonth >= '10/01/2011' and WorkMonth < '01/01/2012'
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of SQL [aggregate functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function). The `SUM` function can be particularly useful:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(MilesLadenToll) as MilesLadenTollTotal, 
    SUM(MilesLadenNonToll) as MilesLadenNonTollTotal 
FROM FuelTaxTripSummary 
WHERE WorkMonth >= '10/01/2011' and WorkMonth < '01/01/2012'
```

This query will provide a single result row with both totals.

As to how to populate the `Label` with the results of the query, I'm completely unfamiliar to C#, but take a look at [How to add text to a WPF Label in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4902464/851811) and at the accepted answer to the following almost duplicate question [C# SQL SUM value to a label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978186/851811).

You should probably be using `executeReader` instead of `executeScalar` in order to get each one of the totals, as suggested in [How to populate more than one column using executescalar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6291716/851811)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know about that SUM option but how do I display the results in labels? I only know how to work with DataGridView's :-)

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not familiar with c#. What GUI framework are you using? If it's Windows Forms, the following class might be what you're looking for: [Label Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx)

Comment: The following question, which also addresses almost the same exact issue can be helpful: [C# SQL SUM value to a label](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4978137/851811)

Comment: Thanks Xavi. The example issue is similar. I had to tweek it quite a bit but after a while I got it working.